# easy way to use getElementsByTagName to change form target?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, target

I have a form in a PHP file that I want to include in various other files which will be in iframes in other pages. In some cases, the form target should be `_top` but in others `_blank`. So it seems to me I should be able to set the target in a separate PHP file and then include the PHP file containing the form in that file. Based on something I found online (I am a novice here), it appeared to me that something as simple as

```
<script type-"text-javascript">
document.getElementsByTagName('form').target = "_top";
</script>
```

should be able to accomplish this. But that didn't work--target was simply default and opened within the iframe. Is there some simple way to accomplish this goal?

Comment: Hint: the method name is getElementsByTagName. Note the **s** at the end of elements

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a collection. Loop through it, or just use `[0]` to get the first...then set the `target` property:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].target = "_top";
```

or

```
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms[i].target = "_top";
}
```

Note that either of these have to be executed **after** the `<form>` is available/rendered on the page. So that means put this code literally **after** the `<form>` or inside of the `window.onload` event.

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName

Comment: This answers the "how to do this in JavaScript" question, but doing it with JavaScript is round about and more prone to error. He also asks what the simplest way to accomplish this. That would be to keep it all in the PHP so the form HTML sent to the client is already in the state it needs to be, i.e. - no Javascript munging of the target. He as much says that the PHP file for the form will be included in the other PHP files.

Comment: @ErikNedwidek That's nice. You provided a PHP solution, I provided a JavaScript solution. I'm not some master PHP programmer and haven't had that much experience with it, so I'll stick with this. You're welcome to help the OP with a PHP path, I'm not able to. If this answer turns out to be too difficult to implement or doesn't work, then so be it. At the same time, if the `target` needs to be set dynamically, PHP won't be able to help. That's all I was trying to answer, with the code they provided

Comment: really didn't mean to step on your toes or insult you (re-reading my comment, I see it could be seen as a bit tactless). It was something more of an interrogatory to make sure that *I* wasn't missing something important.

Comment: @DavidThomas Well crap, of course I did. Hopefully you could see I knew to do that because it was actually included in my second example with the loop

Comment: @ErikNedwidek No problem, I didn't need to respond like that :) I don't think you're missing anything - you have a great point, and it's really just my fault for not knowing how to handle that in PHP (even if it's easy). I think your answer makes sense, I just don't know how their PHP is set up (even though they kind of explain it) and really was just not sure about too many things...and my PHP ignorance. +1 for your answer though!

Comment: Absolutely (also you pretty explicitly stated that was your intent in the sentence beforehand!), but I just wanted to check that I wasn't missing something awesome (I more or less learned JavaScript by accident, so cool stuff seems to pass me by, sometimes).

Comment: @DavidThomas That's actually a good point, I didn't think of it like that. There are several surprising/unexpected things in JavaScript, so it's good to speak up. Especially since it went against what I *said* right before it. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a PHP file to call your form's PHP file, why not just set a variable?

form.php:

```
<form target="<?php echo $target; ?>">
```

parent.php:

```
<?php
$target="_top";
include "form.php";
?>
```

some_other.php:

```
<?php
$target="_blank";
include "form.php";
?>
```

Now my real suggestion would be to be to make your form into a function (eg - outputForm) so that you can do an include_once at the top of every PHP file that needs the form and call outputForm("_blank") where you need the form.

Comment: Thanks so much, this works great. I did ask for javascript but did not realize it was simpler to implement in PHP. I can see that your "real suggestion" might be more elegant, but it's a little advanced for me at this point.